# Sequelize concat in where clause?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do this in sequelize

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_person as p,tbl_employee as e
WHERE CONCAT(p.first_name,' ',last_name) = full_name;
```

how can I convert it in sequelize javascript?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used sequelize before, but after glancing at the documentation, couldn't you use `Sequelize.fn(...)`?

```
Model.findAll({
    where: Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.fn("CONCAT",
        Sequelize.col("first_name"),
        " ",
        Sequelize.col("last_name")
      ),
      {
        eq: Sequelize.col('full_name')
      }
    )
});
```